# Update data in firebase database/passing value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is decrement value "quantity" after click on button "Save". Error will occur when I call function updateTraining from onClick, because passing arguments are null. So my question is How I should correctly pass values from database to updateTraining and decrement quantity value.

Below my code:

```
public class Activity12 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

ListView listViewTraining;
int quantity;
String id;
List<AddTraining> trainingList;
Button buttonUpdate;


DatabaseReference datababaseTraining;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_12);



    datababaseTraining = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Event");

    listViewTraining = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTraining);
    trainingList = new ArrayList<>();

    listViewTraining.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            AddTraining addTraining = trainingList.get(i);


            showUpdateDialog(addTraining.getPlace(), addTraining.getDate(), addTraining.getTime(), addTraining.getQuantity(), addTraining.getId());

            return false;
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    datababaseTraining.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            trainingList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot trainingSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                //First checkout
                AddTraining addtraining = trainingSnapshot.getValue(AddTraining.class);
                System.out.println("check " + addtraining.getPlace());
                System.out.println("check " + addtraining.getTime());
                System.out.println("check " + addtraining.getDate());
                System.out.println("check " + addtraining.getQuantity());
                System.out.println("check " + addtraining.getId());
                trainingList.add(addtraining);



            }

            TrainingList adapter = new TrainingList(Activity12.this, trainingList);
            listViewTraining.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void showUpdateDialog(String place, String date, int time, int quantity, String id){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    System.out.println("checkpoint2 " + quantity);

    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final TextView textViewPlace = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlace2); 
    final TextView textViewDate = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate2);   
    final TextView textViewTime = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime2);   
    final TextView textViewQuantity = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity2);
    buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("More details:");

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    textViewPlace.setText(place);
    textViewDate.setText("Date: " + date);
    textViewTime.setText("Hour: " + String.valueOf(time));
    textViewQuantity.setText("Quantity: " + String.valueOf(quantity));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonUpdate) {
        updateTraining(quantity, id);

    }
}

private void updateTraining( int quantity, String id){
    System.out.println("checkout3 " + quantity);
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Event");
    databaseReference.child(id).child("quantity").setValue(quantity-1);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

}

My structure of db is :

[image]

Comment: not clear what you are doing.. but yes quantity and id are both null, since they never referenced anything in the first place..I guess you already have id in the database right?

Comment: Where is the structure?

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I have edited my post "id" has the same value as child node

Answer (score 0):

do this:

under `Activity` declaration add this:

```
int quantity=0;
```

inside `//onCreate`:

```
datababaseTraining = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Event");


datababaseTraining.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         id=data.getKey();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Now String `id` is equal to the key inside `Event`

Now inside of this `updateTraining(quantity, id);` you should have `quantity=0` and `id=key_of_node`

Answer (score 0):

Your refrence object is null so your db is not updating

```
textViewTime.setText("Hour: " + String.valueOf(time));
textViewQuantity.setText("Quantity: " + String.valueOf(quantity));
```

below this line add this

```
this.quantity = quantity;
this.id=id;
```